# How to use ""Whois Class Code"" script?

Tags: php, whois

```
<?php
require("whoisClass.php")
$whois=new Whois;
$rs=$whois->whoislookup("99webtools.com"); //Your domain or IP
echo '<pre>'.$rs.'</pre>';
?>
```

and this is link to show whoisclass.php

http://99webtools.com/php-whois-script.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a third-party library, not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script has an error which you also have *(copied and pasted from source)*, being the missing semi-colon at the end of:

```
require("whoisClass.php")
                         ^ // <= right there
```

replace with:

```
require("whoisClass.php");
```

and it will run.

Having error reporting on, would have signaled the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$whois' (T_VARIABLE) in /user/home/whois.php on line 3

Always use error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

**Footnotes:**

When an error is reported on a certain line number, many times the error is on the line before that. In this case it signals being on line 3, yet it's actually on line 2.

Comment: And can i apply this script to check domain available ?

Comment: Yes. The registrar's response will automatically show if the domain is available. For example `No match for domain "SRVASDFASFDASFASD.COM".` @user3561081

Comment: @Fred-ii-, How many times should I tell you to not use your _Eagle eye_ ability :P ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Can't help it, it's stronger than me ;-)